# VBA Submit Button Clicking

Tags: php, vba

I'm getting a Run-time error '438' (Object Doesn't support this property or method') when trying to click a button via VBA on a PHP website, and I have been googling for the last few hours and cant find a way around it.

This code below does everything I need it to, but cant find how to click the button without it failing, tried the following:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByName("Calculate").Click
IE.Document.getElementsByID
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName
```

etc all fail.

The code for the button as I see is below:

```
<button onclick="calculate();" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
```

So when using ByClassName I used the btn btn-primary and by Name I used Calculate. I'm losing my mind now lol, any ideas? Code below:

p.s using IE11 if that matters.

```
    Sub testWeb()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim IE As Object

    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim objElement As Object

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'Open IE
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://www.doogal.co.uk/DrivingDistances.php"

    'Wait until site is loaded
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop


    IE.Document.getElementById("startLocs").Value = "TEST"
    IE.Document.getElementById("endLocs").Value = "TEST1"
    IE.Document.getElementsByName("Calculate").Click

    IE.Document.forms(1).submit    


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using VBS on a website? Because if not, please don't.. Go for javascript. VBS is like the evil little underfed brother of JS that no-one likes.

Comment: Its a knowledge gap tbh pal :), I need the info in Excel so I'm using what I know to put in this data.

Comment: Not sure how Rob figures this is VBS... You'd think the several references to VBA would distinguish that. Maybe VBA and VBS are interchangeable terms for JS guys. :) Anyhow, I +1'd it to counteract the -1 just in case it was from someone who didn't read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues with the code posted.

1. The `.getElementsByName` method returns a collection of elements. You will have to figure out which item is the element you want to click. So your code should be something like this:

   `IE.Document.getElementsByName("Calculate").Item(5).Click`
2. If the HTML you posted is from the actual site, then the `<BUTTON>` does not have a `name` property, so it will not be in the collection of elements returned by `getElementsByName`.

You may have to investigate a different method for finding your DOM element. IDK how many buttons are on the form, nor do I know what class is assigned to each button, but perhaps you can `getElementsByTagName` then loop through each `item` looking at its `.class` property or you could `getElementsByClassName` and loop through that collection until you find an element of the `.type` button.

Comment: Boom, you're a legend :). It was the ByClassName I needed and .Item(0).click instead of just click. Boom :)